# Django Rest Framework - How can I serialize a complex many-to-many object model with a custom table join?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django and Django REST Framework.

I have a fairly complex relationship model, the intent is to have a shopping cart with many orders:

```
    
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Order(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='TableJoin')

class TableJoin(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

I'm having trouble both using the ORM to pull a complete `Order` model (with relations), and to then serialize that.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by "pull a complete Order"?

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired output?

Comment: An Order object with all Products, accompanied by the quantity of the product. E.g. `order = Order.objects.get(pk=pk); for i in order.items: print(i.product.name, i.quantity)` but with the accompanying serializer